# Next js 14 Server component data updating after storing new data from client component

Tags: next.js, next.js13

How do I update data in a server component from a client component in NextJS when router.push from client component to server component.I am storing data from a client component then i put router.push in the list page of the data that is server component

I tried router.refresh after it i did router.push('/server/component')

Comment: Have you resolved this?